# Angular material mat-select drop-down size and scroll problem on item select

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, scroll, angular-material

**Goal**:

To have a `mat-select` with `multiple` select but with bigger drop-down size.

**Knows solutions:**

Add `panelClass` to mat-select and customize it's `max-height`. It seems working fine in some cases.

**Problem**

When clicking on items in the drop-down, scroll jumps unexpectedly.

Material trying to center the clicked item to visible view and as we changed the size of drop-down, it's losing sizes and scrolling in the wrong way.

This problem appears only when you have `multiple` select.

[image: Scroll jump problem]

**Possible solution**

- Wait for Material when drop-down size change will be officially implemented. For now, it is constant. `const SELECT_PANEL_MAX_HEIGHT: 256;`
- Don't change the size of drop-down) In this case, the goal will not be reached as we need a bigger drop-down to see more options without scroll.
- Please suggest another option.

**Problem illustration:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-scroll-jumps-on-bigger-size

Comment: i have just had the same problem and I solved by: 
• catching the scroll listening event on the material select 
   -> saving the scrollTop status in an array 
• changing the panel's scrollTop righe after the option click, 
   setting it as it was before it was changed